# Ayuda con archivo 'config.xml' de phonegap

Tags: phonegap

tengo entendido que una aplicación hecha en phonegap no acepta php, pero la aplicación que yo utilizo lo requiere para inicios de sesión y búsquedas de información en una base de datos.
y por un tema al respecto entendí que los archivos php no se incluian para empaquetarse y crear el apk en build.phonegap
resultando esto así, quisiera saber cómo creo la comunicación entre aplicación en el celular y los archivos php que dejé en el servidor (que son con los que se comunica)

*Como pista tengo que en la misma publicación que ví que los php no se incluian para empaquetar, decía que le daba algún permiso.. mas no me quedó bien entendido  eso*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente, no puedes añadir PHP en la aplicación de PhoneGap. Lo que podrías hacer es tener tus ficheros PHP en un servidor (como parece que indicas que ya tienes) y llamarlos usando JavaScript y AJAX.

Esto se podría conseguir de manera sencilla haciendo algo como esto (uso jQuery como ejemplo):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://tudominio.com/tufichero.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { usuario: valorUser, contrasena: valorPassword },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // operaciones a realizar
  }
});
```

Este procedimiento es más o menos estándar y común a cualquier otra aplicación web (con o sin PhoneGap), pero aún hay un paso que debes hacer: por seguridad las consultas a servidores externos pueden estar cortadas por Cordova/PhoneGap, **tienes que añadir una lista blanca de dominios a los que tu aplicación podrá realizar peticiones y consultas**.

Para añadir tu dominio a la lista blanca debes:

1. Instalar el plugin de Whitelist (aunque seguramente ya lo tengas porque viene por defecto en las versiones modernas de Cordova/PhoneGap)
2. Abrir el fichero config.xml
3. Añadir los dominios a los que se les permite acceso:

   ```
   <access origin="http://tudominio.com" />
   ```

---

Referencia y enlaces útiles:

- [Documentación oficial de PhoneGap: Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) (desactualizada, en inglés)
- [Documentación oficial de Cordova: Guía de lista blanca](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/7.x/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html) (en español)
- [Plugin de Whitelist para Cordova/PhoneGap](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) (en inglés)
- [StackOverflow: Loading php content into Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20663052/3695983) (en inglés)

Comment: Muchas gracias, si, el servidor es de la empresa en la que estoy practicando, en el access origin si le había puesto el host de la empresa pero igual el formulario me enviaba al archivo php y me mostraba el código
 jaja
una duda, en la petición ajax que me muestra, así es como tendría que modificar todas las peticiones ajax que tengo?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que te mostraba el código? ¿Te refieres al código PHP? Porque si es eso, el problema puede ser que tu servidor no tiene PHP configurado o hay algún otro error.

Comment: si, me mostraba el código PHP

Comment: Entonces creo que hay problema más grande que solo la llamada AJAX. Parece que tu servidor no está sirviendo correctamente el PHP y eso es un problema de servidor que no tiene que ver con Cordova/PhoneGap.

Comment: Hola, gracias a dios el PHP funciona bien, jeje, la comunicación si se hace bien, partiendo del ejemplo que me mostró, la primera url me envía a un php donde recibe los datos, en el success muestro un msj de error en caso de que los datos no sean correctos, y si si lo son, redirijo a un php, ¿por qué? porque ese php dibuja en el DOM de un html contenido obtenido de una base de datos, ese php tiene la url del html donde se va a mostrar el contenido, entonces a ese php ¿qué ruta del html le asigno para que la muestre en la app?